# Firefox jquery flicker bug problem

Tags: jquery, firefox

This is possibly a really silly question but I've stared at this code way too long for it to make sense!

I'm having problems with a flicker of the screen in firefox; It is related a filtering script...

I have a website that is a one page vertical scroll; with different anchors to define sections and a smooth scroll script to make it pretty...

See the example here: http://www.moonshine.net.au/index-new.html

I've tried everything... Please help me, I'm begging you, my eyes hurt!

Comment: I am using Firefox and the page looks perfectly good. Which version and platform you are using? For me, it's: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100214 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.8`.

Comment: The problem is occurring using Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 
It happens when manually scrolling after clicking various tabs in the 'our work' section, very fast. Appreciate your time!

Comment: nope. no flickerings. win 7 firefox 3.6.2. no mac though

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess.

In your **scroll.js** file, this event handler:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function()...
```

is being applied to those 'sub-navigation' elements under the Portfoliio section, so when you click on one, a scroll animation is taking place on the `body`, which is interfering with your attempt to manually scroll.

If you exempt those links from getting that event handler, I'm guessing it will clear up.